# NullPointerException when I use sum function in hibernate 5

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm using the following code:

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<?> criteria = builder.createQuery();
Root<?> root = criteria.from(TblAgahi.class);
criteria.multiselect(builder.function("SUM", Object.class, root.get("id")));
List<?> resultList = entityManager.createQuery(criteria).getResultList();
```

When i execute this code on `hibernate 4.1.8.final` it work fine but when i update my hibernate to `5.2.1.final` I get `NullPointerException`.

```
the Exception is:
    java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.hibernate.dialect.function.StandardAnsiSqlAggregationFunctions$SumFunction.determineJdbcTypeCode(StandardAnsiSqlAggregationFunctions.java:200)
    at org.hibernate.dialect.function.StandardAnsiSqlAggregationFunctions$SumFunction.getReturnType(StandardAnsiSqlAggregationFunctions.java:158)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.IdentNode.getDataType(IdentNode.java:327)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.MethodNode.getFirstArgumentType(MethodNode.java:59)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.SqlGenerator.endFunctionTemplate(SqlGenerator.java:211)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.SqlGeneratorBase.methodCall(SqlGeneratorBase.java:2538)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.SqlGeneratorBase.selectExpr(SqlGeneratorBase.java:2102)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.SqlGeneratorBase.selectColumn(SqlGeneratorBase.java:1914)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.SqlGeneratorBase.selectClause(SqlGeneratorBase.java:544)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.SqlGeneratorBase.selectStatement(SqlGeneratorBase.java:186)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.SqlGeneratorBase.statement(SqlGeneratorBase.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.generate(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:244)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:142)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:115)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:77)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:152)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.getQueryPlan(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:521)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:623)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:3250)
    at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.CriteriaQueryImpl$1.buildCompiledQuery(CriteriaQueryImpl.java:318)
    at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaCompiler.compile(CriteriaCompiler.java:127)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:3543)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:203)
    at com.advertisement.database.DbHelper.test(DbHelper.java:432)
    at com.advertisement.database.DbHelper.find(DbHelper.java:278)
    at com.advertisement.database.DbEntityRepository.find(DbEntityRepository.java:148)
    at com.advertisement.controller.Test.test(Test.java:28)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:247)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:267)
    at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:149)
    at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:813)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at com.advertisement.lifecycle.OverrideEncodingFilter.doFilter(OverrideEncodingFilter.java:22)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I know i can do above code by `builder.sum(...)` function but i want to do it by `builder.function(...)` method.

Comment: yes me too, to solve that make your filter by a simple loop after request result, but it's a waiting solution until bug resolution on hibernate

Answer (score 0):

I have just fixed [HHH-9931](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9331) and it will be released in Hibernate ORM 5.2.13.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use SUM function, you should use

```
builder.sum(root.get("id"));
```

instead of

```
builder.function("SUM", Object.class, root.get("id"));
```